# how to change the system default printer using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

is there any way in which I can use VBA to change the system default printer? As well as changing its settings? Or is it too much to ask from VBA T-T

Comment: yes you can. Do you know the printer name? have you tried any code so fare?

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I've found the way to do it :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You need to execute a shell script from your VBA code:

```
Sub ChangePrinter()
    Shell "RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n ""HP LaserJet 3000"""
End Sub
```

(change `HP LaserJet 3000` to whatever your printer name is).

If your printer is on network location (e.g. `HP LaserJet 3000 on 192.168.1.100`) use this syntax:

```
Shell "RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n ""\\192.168.1.100\HP LaserJet 3000"""
```

Also it's possible to change printer settings, but you will need a `.dat` file with necessary settings.

To get the current settings from printer:

```
Shell "RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Ss /n ""HP LaserJet 3000"" /a ""C:\your_settings.dat"" u"
```

To feed the settings file to your printer's driver:

```
Shell "RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Sr /n ""HP LaserJet 3000"" /a ""C:\your_settings.dat"" u"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have tested the code, it works greatly for me. But because I want to choose the default printer by choosing from a list in excel without opening the code and make changes to it every time,  I stored my printer's names to a variable and tried to replace it with "HP LaserJet 3000", but it cant work and the com ask me to check the printer's name... is there any way I can make this right?

Comment: How do you add it to the string? You should concatenate the string like this: `............" & PrinterNameVariable & "............`

Comment: I used the following line:

Comment: Sub PrinterSetup()

Comment: Dim Printer As String

Comment: Printer = range("c18").Value

Comment: Shell ("RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n " & Printer & "")

Comment: Just to add: i think maybe the problem is that my printer name contains spaces and the string variable cannot pass the spaces properly so that the code only take the first part of the name before the space......

Comment: As i tried one other function and the name mentioned in the msgbox popped up is exactly the first part of my printer's name

Comment: You need to enclose your printer name in quotes if it contains spaces:
`Shell "RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n """ & Printer & """...`
Note the **double quotes.**